# SharePoint 2010 List Application Page Ribbon

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How do I add the default ribbon to a Custom application page for a list.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need to set the master page for your application page. MSDN says -

> By default, an Application Page item references the master page of the site that you are using to debug your project. That page is named v4.master and you can find it listed in the Master Page Gallery of the SharePoint site. You can explicitly change which master page is used by the application page by setting the MasterPageFile attribute of the application Page element. (For example: MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/applicationv4.master"). In fact, you must set this attribute if dynamic master pages are not enabled on the SharePoint server.